how to convert a double field to a string field remove decimal and zero
in a r script why when converting a double field to a character field, it adds a dot and a decimal to a duckdb table, how can i fix this?
import duckdb

# Connect to DuckDB database
con = duckdb.connect(database=':memory:')

# Create a sample table for demonstration
con.execute("""
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id INTEGER, 
    double_column DOUBLE
)
""")
con.execute("""
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES 
    (1, 10.5), 
    (2, 20.7), 
    (3, 30.9)
""")

# Add a new column to store the converted result
con.execute("""
ALTER TABLE my_table 
ADD COLUMN string_column VARCHAR
""")

# Convert DOUBLE to VARCHAR and remove decimals
con.execute("""
UPDATE my_table
SET string_column = TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM CAST(double_column AS VARCHAR))
""")

# Display the updated table
updated_table = con.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table").fetchdf()
print(updated_table)

# Disconnect from the database
con.close()



That TRIM() call only removes . at the end of the value. But the decimal is not at the end, there's a digit after it.

Use SPLIT_PART(CAST(double_column AS VARCHAR), '.', 1) to return everything before the .

Or cast double_column to an integer and then cast that to a string.
